# readerManager.EstablishContext() showing exception - UAE_IDCardLib.dll

Tags: winforms, dll, c#-4.0, smartcard-reader

I created a dotnet desktop application using c# to read the emirates id card data.

```
            ReaderManagement readerManager;
            PCSCReader reader;
            try
            {
                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("before reader");
                readerManager = new ReaderManagement();
                readerManager.EstablishContext();
                readerManager.DiscoverReaders();
```

On line  `readerManager.EstablishContext()` I am getting an exception

Unable to load DLL 'UAE_IDCardLib.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

Platform target is x86

Comment: Well, it either cannot find that module or the dll has a different bitness. Verify what's what